# git maintenance with worktrees

Tags: git, git-worktree, git-maintenance

Let's say I have a repository and have multiple worktrees,

e.g.:

```
git clone https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife
cd Spoon-Knife\
git worktree add -b myfix ../myfix main
git worktree add -b myfix2 ../myfix2 main
```

Let's imagine *Spoon-Knife* is a really big repository and I want git to take care of speeding things up. Do I need to call `git maintenance start` on every worktree or is it just fine to call it once on the folder *Spoon-Knife*?

I am suspecting I only need it once but if I call it on other worktrees git doesn't complain either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only once.

All Git worktrees share the same repository. They just link to it (with the exception of the main worktree where it resides). But
each worktree has a few things of its own:

- The index
- `HEAD`
- Pseudorefs like `MERGE_HEAD`
- Per-worktree configuration files
- Per-worktree refs

git-maintenance(1) does maintenance on the repository. For example the
garbage collection (git-gc(1)) optimizes the object layout and removes
objects that are unreachable. We can infer that garbage collection takes
into account absolutely all refs including per-worktree refs, since if
it didn’t running it would be dangerous. And since it takes into account
all refs we can infer that it cleans up things relative to each
worktree.

All the other per-worktree metadata are either vital (the index) or just
a small handful of files that keep state (like `MERGE_HEAD`).

So yes, only once is enough. This is in fact one of the direct benefits
of using worktrees instead of multiple clones.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to run git maintenance start once on the main repository (in this case, the Spoon-Knife directory). This command initiates maintenance tasks such as garbage collection, which optimize the repository for performance.

Git worktrees are linked to the main repository and share its object store, so maintenance tasks performed on the main repository will also affect the worktrees. Therefore, running git maintenance start on the main repository will optimize all worktrees associated with it.

Running git maintenance start on individual worktrees won't cause any errors, but it's unnecessary duplication since the maintenance tasks are already performed on the main repository. Therefore, it's best practice to run it only once on the main repository to avoid redundancy.